# Play Framework 1.2.4: Selected Option for #{select} template

Tags: java, model-view-controller, web-applications, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am passing a `Model` and a `List<String>` from controller to `.html` file using the `render` method invocation. The `Model` passed contains some values that has to be populated in different components present in the UI and the `List<String>` is used for binding with the combo-box.

For binding the `List<String>` with combo-box in the `.html` using the below code and this is working fine:

```
#{select 'employee.role', items:userRoles, valueProperty:'userRoles', labelProperty:'userRoles'/}
```

**What I want to achieve:**

Suppose the `List<String>` contains the roles as `Trainer`, `Educator`, `Trainee`, `Staff` and the `Model` passed has a `role` property with value `Staff`. When the page loads, then `Staff` should be in `selected` state in the combo-box display.

**Problem**

I am aware of how to iterate through a `List` in Play framework template but I am not aware of how to keep a value `selected` in the drop-down based on one of the property values present in the `Model`

Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/tags#select):

> This tag can generate options using items attribute.
>
> - items (optional) - list of objects, used to create options
> - value (optional) - selected element in items (note that multiple selections are not supported)
> - labelProperty (optional) - for each item, attribute used as option’s label
> - valueProperty (optional) - for each item, attribute used as option’s value. id is used by default

So, the code should be:

```
#{select 'employee.role', items: userRoles, value: model.role /}
```